# C# Password generator, generate more than one password

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

*SOLVED*

I'm working with a password generator and it works with one password. But I want to generate more than one if I want to.

My design look like this:
[image]

If I choose length more than 1, it generates a password with one character, but I don't know how to do if I want to generate more than one password.
Any suggestions? My code looks like this on the button:

```
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        length = (int)numericUpDownPasswordlength.Value;
        totalPasswords = (int)numericUpDownPassword.Value;
        string[] minatecken = symb;

        for (; length > 0; length--)
        {
            sw.Write(minatecken[rnd.Next(0, 62)]);
        }

        richTextBoxPasswords.Text = sw + "\n";
```

Codeanswer, thanks to David:

```
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StringBuilder sb = sw.GetStringBuilder();

        length = (int)numericUpDownPasswordlength.Value;
        totalPasswords = (int)numericUpDownPassword.Value;
        string[] minatecken = symb;

        for (; totalPasswords > 0; totalPasswords--)
        {
            for (var i = length; i > 0; i--)
            {
                sw.Write(minatecken[rnd.Next(0, 62)]);
            }

            richTextBoxPasswords.Text += sw + "\n";
            sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're looking one value to generate a single password, so you'd just have to wrap that in another loop to generate a list of passwords.  Each iteration of that loop would be the single password implementation you have now.  Something like this:

```
for (; totalPasswords > 0; totalPasswords--)
{
    for (var i = length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        sw.Write(minatecken[rnd.Next(0, 62)]);
    }
    richTextBoxPasswords.Text += sw + "\n";
}
```

Comment: It still gives me one password. If I for example choose 3 passwords with 3 characters (length) and I debug this, it loops through the first for loop 3 times, but my length becomes 0 after the first round of looping..

Comment: @Kriistiian: Ah, I see the problem.  I've updated the answer to reflect this.  Your loop was *modifying* `length`, but should instead be modifying a *copy* of `length` each time, preserving the original value.

Comment: Nice one! Somehow I need to clear my stringwriter before executing the next password.. It generates more than one password but the old value also gets to the second row. For example: If I choose 2 passwords with 2 length, and I get "G5" generated on first row, then I get on the second row "G5TY" etc..

Comment: Solved it with a 'StringBuilder', see my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Execute your password generation block within a `for` loop:

```
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    length = (int)numericUpDownPasswordlength.Value;
    totalPasswords = (int)numericUpDownPassword.Value;

    for (int pwdCount=0; pwdCount < totalPasswords; pwdCount++)
    {
        string[] minatecken = symb;

        for (; length > 0; length--)
        {
            sw.Write(minatecken[rnd.Next(0, 62)]);
        }

        richTextBoxPasswords.Text = sw + "\n";
    }
```

That should create and display the number of passwords contained in `totalPasswords`

Comment: Same as above. It still gives me one password. If I for example choose 3 passwords with 3 characters (length) and I debug this, it loops through the first for loop 3 times, but my length becomes 0 after the first round of looping..